# Как задать тип для аргумента функции из динамически сформированного массива?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть класс

```
class Constants {
  static LocaleCodes = {
    English: {
      code: 'en',
      value: 'English',
    },
    Russian: {
      code: 'ru',
      value: 'Русский',
    },
    Chinese: {
      code: 'ch',
      value: '中国人',
    },
  };

  static Locales = Object.keys(I18nConstants.LocaleCodes).map(
    (locale) => I18nConstants.LocaleCodes[locale].code
  );
}
```

Хочу создать функцию которая будет принимать, в качестве аргумента, только набор элементов из массива `Constants.Locales`

Прочитал что можно сделать вот так:

```
  static Locales = Object.keys(I18nConstants.LocaleCodes).map(
    (locale) => I18nConstants.LocaleCodes[locale].code
  ) as const;
```

и в самой функции написать

```
someFoo(lang: typeof Constants.Locales[number]) {
....
}
```

Такой способ действительно работает, если массив статический, но как указать тип из динамически сформированного массива, не представляю.

Может быть есть какой-то способ, чтобы указать тип из объекта `LocaleCodes`?

Что-то вроде:

```
someFoo(lang: typeof Constants.LocaleCodes[key]['code']) {
....
}
```

Comment: Нет нельзя. TS не может знать какие значения могут быть у динмически меняющегося массива. Это же компилируемый язык и статический потому на момент компиляции всё должно быть предопределено. Представьте себе что браузеры умеют работать напрямую с TS, мы объявлем массив и говорим, что значения могут быть только отсюда. А потом приходит другой и пишет ф-ал, позволяющий юзеру через инпут дописывать значения в наш массив. Как в этом случае TS должен значть, что массив изменился? Именно никак, потому что он уже скопилировался. Некоторые детали я наверное не совсем точно описал, но в целом суть такая

Comment: Ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662208/types-from-both-keys-and-values-of-object-in-typescript подходит для решения моей задачи

Comment: Так там тоже используется `as const`, который делает объект `readonly`. Если попытаться в него что-то добавить, то TS будет ругаться. Это не динамеческий объект. Если вам заранее известны все допустимые значеня, тогда да, ответ подходит

Comment: В моем случае LocaleCodes это константа, а все что ниже - ее производные. поэтому если меняться и будет то только руками